# Pipeline' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with my code, I want to see the feature importance about vector from word2vec model, but I can't beacause it's a pipeline. Someone could help me to find a solution please ?

```
## Import the random forest model.
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier  
## This line instantiates the model. 
rf = Pipeline([
    ("word2vec vectorizer", MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(w2v)),
    ("Random_forest",  RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=6,random_state=0))])
## Fit the model on your training data.
rf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
## And score it on your testing data.
rf.score(X_test, y_test)

X = model.wv.syn0
X = X.astype(int)

def plot_feat_imp(model, X): 
    Feature_Imp = pd.DataFrame([X, rand_w2v_tfidf.feature_importances_]).transpose(
    ).sort_values(1, ascending=False)
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
    sns.barplot(y=Feature_Imp.loc[:, 0], x=Feature_Imp.loc[:, 1], data=Feature_Imp, orient='h')
    plt.title("Importance des variables (qu'est ce qui explique le mieux la satisfaction)", fontsize=21)
    plt.show()
    return 

MY PROBLEM IS HERE 
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'

plot_feat_imp(gbc_w2v, X)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you were seeking for, but if you want the feature_importances_ of your pipeline object you might want to first get into the best classifier.

This is possible with:

```
rf_fit = rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
feature_importances = rf_fit.best_estimator_._final_estimator.feature_importances_
```

Hope that helps.